# Class not found in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, classpath

I am encountering NoClassDefFoundError despite have required JAR file in my classpath. Attached is the screenshot for same[image]

Comment: That's the build path. Does eclipse use it for running as well as building?

Comment: Sorry I mean buildpath  I am encountering the error at runtime

Comment: buildpath is used for building, that is, by compiler - for runtime check the run (or debug)  configuration used to run it ("txtToExcelUtil" probably) ((Menu: Run -> Run Configurations...))